# chronoformsv5 - how to retrive current email user and send email as a copy

Tags: email, dynamic, joomla3.0, chronoforms

I'm writing a form with chronoformsv5.

I need to send a CC email to the current user email, so I did:

1. hidden field with this value

   ```
   Field Name = current_user_email
   Field ID = current_user_email
   Field Value = <?php echo $current_user_email; ?>
   ```
2. on OnLoad action a create a new action with this code

   ```
   <?php
   $user = JFactory::getUser();
   $current_user_email = $user->email;
   //echo $current_user_email;
   ?>
   ```
3. onSubmit action I create use "email Action" with this value

   ```
   Dynamic To = current_user_email
   Reply To Email = noreply@domain.com
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this FAQ](https://www.chronoengine.com/faqs/56-chronoforms/cfv4/cfv4-other-faqs/2586-how-can-i-get-information-about-the-user). You do not need to get this information until after the form is submitted.